# "View" "Object" "Add" On Bottom Toolbar have Collapsed into a Menu, How Do I Undo This?

Tags: 3d-view, customization, shortcut

I was building a model and at some point I must have clicked some shortcut and now part of my bottom toolbar has collapsed into a menu. It's quite annoying because I manually switch my views in this project quite often. I closed blender and loaded it up again, the default project showed the full toolbar but when I opened my project up again it was gone once again.

In the photo, I have selected the new collapsed menu with my mouse to show what I mean.

[image: View, Object and Add have collapsed into a menu on the bottom toolbar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on this collapsed menu (hamburger) then *Header* and *Collapse Menus*.

[image: Menu]